# Does NI Multisim simulates op-amp input and output noise?

Tags: noise, simulation, multisim

I just created a circuit with AD620 in-amp and I'm worried that there is not enough noise.

I wonder if Multisim simulates advanced op-amp/in-amp properties, like input noise and such?

I mean, if I pick medium noise op-amp with 10nV/rt(Hz) - does it produce noise like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10uV/rt(Hz) is a really noisy op-amp. Most/average ones are about 50nV/rt(Hz).

If you are unsure then look for noise on your transient analysis screen - I'm presuming (not having used Multisim) that you can adjust the transient analysis screen so that the Y axis is just a few micro-volts top to bottom?

Another way around this is to approximately calculate what the noise amplitude might be at the inputs and add a voltage source that generates noise or even a sinewave. For instance if you have 100kHz bandwidth and the op-amp noise is 10nV/rt(Hz) then the equivalent input RMS noise voltage will be 3.16 uV. If you multiplied this by 6.6 you get a decent representation of p-p noise. Next, set your added voltage source to be this amplitude.

Comment: Reason of my question is lazy approach, I wondered if I can do simulation in Multisim instead of all noise calculations or experimening on real hardware. And I meant 10nV, 10uV was mistake, I corrected that.

Comment: Bottom line is to do both. You do a sim so that your 1st iteration PCB is usually you last iteration. Sim saves an iteration in most cases but you need to be rigorous at sim to get the full benefits AND double check or validate performance on real prototypes.

Comment: Later im gonna measure noises in prototype anyway. I expect them to be much lower than desired, thats why I went "lazy mode".